# Is it possible to draw a line chart in Gridpanel using ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJS for GUI. I want to plot a line chart inside a Grid Panel. Is this possible? If so, how do we do this?

Regards,
Anandan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea:

Define a custom renderer function (set a renderer on the column definition).

In the renderer, generate markup for an iframe that references the Google Charts API.

(I'm not familiar with Ext charts - you'd probably want to end up with those ...)

Comment: ext charts = flash = :(
EJSChart is pretty good would be reasonably easy to integrate. The question is how to put the div in a cell.. +1 with the custom renderer